# texture preview for displacement in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

Why, when I'm using the Blender internal renderer, can I see my procedural texture (for my displacement), but, when I'm using Cycles render, I cannot? It's not like I want the procedural texture for texturing; it's for displacement, so why is it not possible to see this when I use Cycles?

It's very annoying for me. Maybe there is a trick using the node editor to show this texture, but I don't know how do do that. I think it's the best way to have a preview directly in the properties panel.

[image: texture preview in Blender Internal]

[image: No texture preview in cycles]

Comment: You aren't the only one ;). Most of the time I'll switch to BI for a second, just so the preview will display (it shouldn't mess anything up). I don't think there is actually any way to do this, the closest is [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1691/599). However you can only use cycles textures, which are different from BI textures (the ones used for displacement).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been added as of [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rB6601136aaa9df5c813741ddb72daf1c2de5962f7) (will be in 2.72).

[image]

Any recent [development build](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3438/599) will have this.

Comment: Thats not true! You got this Wood texture preview just by switching to BI. As soon as you select any of cycles node - that preview texture will disappear. Extremely annoying. A workaround on this i found is a build which mimics UE4 game engine inside blender's textured or material viewport - not the best solution, because it doesnt read cycles "Shaders" nodes. Instead, it does use textures directly. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaFAqBlznmI

Comment: @ЕвгенийГейзер You can see in the top left corner of my screenshot that the current engine is set to Cycles. It still works fine for me in the current release (2.78). Selecting cycles material nodes seems to have no effect on the preview in any way. Can you clarify what you mean? It should be noted that *cycles* uses its own procedural textures (found in the material nodes), and *blender's* textures (editable in the properties panel) have no direct effect on cycles (but they can indirectly effect things, e.g. you can use them to displace a mesh which is fed to cycles).