# How to color lips?

Tags: modeling, texture-painting, vertex-paint

[image: I am trying to color the lips of my sculpt but vertex paint won't overwrite the material and texture paint doesn't seem to work]

How do you select only the vertexes of the lips to color them? I am really confused

Comment: you could create a mask for the lips, there was a recent topic on lips here, it may help: https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-to-get-wet-skin-and-lips/1262283/9

Comment: and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56152/how-to-fade-one-material-into-the-other/56167#56167