# How to reset view node shortcut

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I'm simply trying to use the "view node" on the node editor. I watched a video where I learned the shortcut is ctrl - shift, but it will not work.

Here I'm trying to view a wave texture:

[image]

Am I doing this right? or do I need to reset the shortcut?

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: This behaviour is a part of Node Wrangler addon, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1691/way-of-seeing-data-as-image-anywhere-in-a-cycles-nodes-setup. No need to reset any shortcut, just make sure addon is enabled and you click on the node itself. The result can be seen while in Rendered shading mode if reviewing material nodes.

Answer (score 4):

While [DaurteFarrajotaRamos's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49867/5705) is correct that there is no viewer node *by default*, Greg Zaal's [Node Wrangler](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Nodes/Node_Wrangler) addon (which comes bundled with Blender) does implement a veiwer node of sorts in the node editor.

With Node Wrangler on, when you <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click a node it will connect it to the *Material Output* node, making it visible on the object and in the preview rollout pane.  It will connect surface shaders directly to the *Surface* output, volume shaders directly to the *Volume* output, and all other datatypes (colors, vectors, and values) will be sent through an emission shader plugged inot the *Surface* output.

Answer (score 2):

View node is available for compositing node trees only, not material or texture ones. You seem to be using Blender Cycles nodes in your image, so for those there is no preview node available.

If you want to preview the created material either use the interactive preview in the 3D window by drawing a border around your object with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> or use the preview panel in the Properties Window > Material Tab > Preview