# Cycles hard edges in retroreflective material within a face

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, node-editor, artifacts

I have a problem with a retroreflective material in Cycles. When i render my scene it seems that some faces get rendered differently. The scene contains only one lightsource in form of an emitting Icosphere.

[image: Rendered scene]

The following picture shows the used node setup.

[image: Node Setup for retroreflective material]

Can anybody tell  me the reason for the effect and maybe a solution? I want to achieve a smooth lighting without hard edges, as it would occur in a real world.

Comment: I suspect you normal map may be off in some way. How does it look with the normal inputs disconnected?

Comment: That fixes the problem.
Also when i UV unwrap the face the issue is solved! Thanks @gandalf3

Answer (score 1):

This kind of symptom strikes me indicative of a normals problem. If blender believes that different parts of a flat surface are facing different ways (and therefor reflecting different amounts of light), check the normals.

Try disconnecting normal sockets on the shaders. If that gets rid of the artifacts, try [previewing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1969/599) what you're passing into the normal inputs to see what exactly is wrong.