# What is Node Wrangler Used For?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

Can someone explain to me the basic concepts behind why one would want to use the Node Wrangler add-on?  Thanks for the time!

Comment: http://gregzaal.github.io/node-wrangler/ The addon makes working with nodes a lot faster and easier.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1691/way-of-seeing-data-as-image-anywhere-in-a-cycles-nodes-setup

Comment: Thanks @MrZak!  I actually looked at that post and didn't read all the way down where the answer was.  My bad